error during build: RollupError: Expression expected
I am meeting an error while build react with vite app for production .  However it working npm run start without issue.
I've ensured that all dependencies are up to date and that the configuration settings align.
Advice anyone got this issue before
at getRollupError (file:///.../node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:394:41) at ParseError.initialise (file:///.../node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:11389:28) at convertNode (file:///.../node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13143:10) at convertProgram (file:///.../node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12460:12) at Module.setSource (file:///.../node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:14304:24) at async ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:///.../node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18957:13) 
npm run build 
 "scripts": { "start": "vite", "build": "vite build", "preview": "vite preview", "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.js\"", "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js src/**/*.js", "lint:fix": "eslint src/**/*.js --fix" },
